# React-native: RNSvgPackage() error

Tags: android, react-native

So I'm getting an error (at the bottom) that's most likely caused by me trying uninstalling `react-native-pathjs-charts`. The problem below only exists on android and not on ios.

## Error:

/Users/a.lau/Projects/react-native/First_App/android/app/src/main/java/com/first_app/MainApplication.java:7: error: cannot find symbol
import com.horcrux.svg.RNSvgPackage;
                      ^
  symbol:   class RNSvgPackage
  location: package com.horcrux.svg
/Users/a.lau/Projects/react-native/First_App/android/app/src/main/java/com/first_app/MainApplication.java:29: error: cannot find symbol
            new RNSvgPackage()
                ^
  symbol: class RNSvgPackage
2 errors
:app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.

  > Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 5.997 secs
Could not install the app on the device, read the error above for details.
Make sure you have an Android emulator running or a device connected and have
set up your Android development environment:
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/android-setup.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you did not unlink before uninstalling the module. Install again, unlink and then uninstall the module.

```
npm install react-native-pathjs-charts --save
react-native unlink react-native-svg
npm remove react-native-pathjs-charts --save
```

Comment: unrelated to this current question, but the reason why I uninstalled was that I couldn't get the charts to work, it was giving me another sort of RNS error I believe. Have you ever come across that?

Comment: I haven't used `react-native-pathjs-charts`. Honestly I coudn't find any good chart library, so I just used `react-native-svg` for creating chart in one of my project.

Comment: same, just trying to find a chart library :\\\ I'll give `react-native-svg` a whirl.

Answer (score 3):

Also have in mind that the package was changed from:

```
import com.horcrux.svg.RNSvgPackage;
```

to

```
import com.horcrux.svg.SvgPackage;
```

so you have to change from `new RNSvgPackage()` to `new SvgPackage()`

hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

Run with `yarn add package_name` is helped me.